# Writing a subquery instead of using a spreadshet

Tags: sql

Pretty basic SQL uses, I usually do some basic joins, and then pull data into Sheets to pivot or filter it to get what I want, but know I can do it quicker all in SQL.

For this query, I want to only return data if the c2.id count is greater than 0. I tried writing a subquery in the where clause, but feels like I need to group by task_id for this to be right...can someone help me understand what I should do and why?

```
select t.inserted_at::date, count (distinct c2.id), t.id, t.conversation_id
from tasks t 
left join users u on u.id = t.creator_id 
left join "comments" c2 on t.id = c2.task_id 
left join conversations c on c.id = t.conversation_id 
where u.include_in_metrics = true 
and c.type = 'PROJECT_FEED'
group by 1,3,4
order by t.inserted_at::date desc;
```

Comment: What you want might be RDBMS agnostic but as the description of the `sql` tag description indicates, you should tag the implementation (e.g., oracle) you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this after the `group by` before `order by`

```
having count(distinct c2.id)>0
```